# pyCharm: safe refactoring information for application on depending code

Tags: python, refactoring, pycharm

If I do refactoring in a library pyCharm does handle all depending applications which are known to the current running pyCharm instance.

But code which is not known to the current pyCharm does not get updated.

Is there a way to store the refactoring information in version control, so that depending applications can be updated if they get the update to the new version of the library?

Use Case:

```
class Server:
    pass
```

gets renamed to

```
class ServerConnection:
    pass
```

If a team mate updates the code of my library, his usage of `Server` needs to be changed to `ServerConnection`.

It would be very nice if pyCharm (or an other tool) could help my team mate to update his code automatically.

Comment: Send your team an email `Please change Server to ServerConnection` it's always a good practice to announce API changes  Besides their unit tests will fail prompting them to make changes.

Comment: @qarma Yes, communication in the team is important. But a message to the team mates like `run script foo to update your code` is even better. Of course the script should be human readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not possible neither with a vanilla PyCharm nor with a plugin nor with a 3rd party tool.

1. It is not mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/refactoring-source-code.html)
2. There is no such plugin in the [JetBrains Plugin Repositories](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=pycharm&search=refactor)
3. If PyCharm writes refactoring information to it's internal logs, you could build this yourself (but would you really want to?)
4. I am also not aware of any python specific refactorig tool that does that. You can check for yourself: there is another [SO question for the most popular refactoring tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796/what-refactoring-tools-do-you-use-for-python)

**But ...**

I am sure there are reasons why your situation is like it is - there always are good reasons (and most of the time the terms 'historic and 'grown' turn up in explanations of these reasons) but I still feel obligated to point out what [qarma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705086/qarma) already mentioned in his comment: the fact that you want to do something like replaying a refactoring on a different code base points towards a problem that should be solved in a different way.

**Alternative 1: introduce an API**

If you have different pieces of software that depend on each other on such a deep level, it might be a good idea to define an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) that decouples the code bases from each others internals. With an API it is clear which parts have to be stable. If changes have to be done on the API level they must be communicated and coordinated with the involved teams.

**Alternative 2: Make it what it actually is: one code base**

If A1 for whatever reason is not possible I would conclude that you actually have one system distributed over different code bases and then those should be merged into one code base. Different teams can still work on the same code base (hopefully using a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control)) but global refactorings can be done with tooling help and they reach all parts of the system.

**Alternative 3: Make these refactorings in PyCharm over all involved code bases**

Even if you can't merge them into one code base you could combine them easily in PyCharm by [loading different projects into the same Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/opening-multiple-projects.html). I do this without problems with two git projects that have to be in different repositories but still share certain aspects. PyCharm handles commits to these repositories transparently: if you make changes in several repositories and commit them you write one commit message and the commits will be done to all repositories.

Comment: Feedback to "Alternative 2 (one code base)". We have one core app and for every customer we have a separate repo. I think one code base does not scale. Alternative 3 looks better: Up to now I can still load the code of all cusomters into pyCharm. But if the number of customers grows, it gets harder ....

Comment: @guettli I would strongly recommend to work towards a clearly defined API between library code and the (growing number of) customer apps using the library (or extract the library, if you're cloning the whole base for every customer). I am sure you'll be glad you did it when your customer base keeps growing and growing.

Comment: Do you always get it right on the first time? Our team does not. That's what the question is about. Some API updates are easy and can be done automatically.

Comment: No I definitely do **not** get everything right the first time - sorry for sounding like a little know-it-all :) ... this is why I said "work towards an API" and proposed Alternative 3 to ease the pain. I guess I should have known that you are doing that anyway, but I tend to state the obvious sometimes, as I am never quite sure if what's obvious to me is obvious to somebody else.

Comment: Thank you Oliver for your advice. I give you the bounty.

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be interesting to hear in a few months (maybe in form of a new answer), which approach finally worked for you.