# Change the a parameter or name of the function all over the .py files

Tags: python

I have the different .py files (~10). For example, here is two function in two different .py files. So, I want to change the parameter b to c, and the name of function sum to new_name and I want to change them all over the other .py files. Do we have any option in python for that:

f1.py:

```
def sum(a,b):
 return a+b
```

f2.py:

```
import f1
def foo(a,b):
 return a+2*b + sum(a,b)
```

The code which I want is output:

f1.py:

```
def new_name(a,c):
 return a+c
```

f2.py:

```
def foo(a,c):
 return a+2*c + new_name(a,c)
```

Comment: If you use vscode then it has a pretty handy search and replace feature... Nothing like that is built into python though, I am sure there are other IDE's that implement similar features as well

Comment: You may iterate over the .py files contained in your folder, using `listdir` and then replace the target strings in these files by following the steps outlined here: https://pythonexamples.org/python-replace-string-in-file/

Comment: There is nothing built into python (or other languages). However you can use such feature in many IDEs on the market. The feature is mostly called "Refactoring" and is mostly done by pressing "F2" while having the cursor on a identifier (function name, var-name etc). In most cases this will be executed project-wide.

Comment: Using _IDE-assisted_ refactoring could help here. E.g. [Rename refactoring in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rename-refactorings.html) - also works for parameter-names. See also [Refactoring tools for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796/what-refactoring-tools-do-you-use-for-python/26381548#26381548) (with interesting PyBowler CLI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for, i.e. IDE vs a Python-based solution, but here is a small script you can use to iterate over the files in your directory, open them, search and replace text. This could be finnicky to work with though, depending on the contents of your file:

```
import os

def replace_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read()

    # Replace occurrences of 'sum' with 'new_name' and 'b' with 'c' per OP instructions
    new_contents = file_contents.replace('sum(', 'new_name(').replace(', b', ', c')

    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_contents)

# Directory containing the .py files
directory = '/path/to/directory'

# Loop over all .py files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        replace_in_file(file_path)
```